# check input type text and radio

Tags: javascript, html

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/22/ I create a form with radio button and text input. I would like to check if in form all inputs are completed. I know check radio button, but text input is not working properly. Can you check my code?

```
if ($('input[name="age"].value') == null || $('input[name="age"].value') == "") {
alert("is filled");
}
else {
alert("is not filled");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/24/

```
if ($('input[name=age]').val() === "") {
     alert("is not filled");
} else {
    alert("is filled");
}
```

Comment: === what does it mean? is it null and "" together?

Comment: it is a strict comparison, there is a difference between == and === in Js. please google it.

Comment: both should work in this case. but it is a good practice to use ===

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong, use

`$('input[name="age"]').val() == null`

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
if ($('input[name="age"]').val() == "") { 
    alert("is filled");
}else {
    alert("is not filled");
}
```

You had set it to `input[name="age"].value`, which means get an `<input>` element with a `name` attribute having value `age` and a class `value`.

Hope that helps!